# Add columns to Entity Fields view in CRM365

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is it possible to edit the "Fields" view for entities in Customizations in CRM 365? I want to be able to see field requirement without having to click in every field.

[image: CRM customizations screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it possible to modify the view/columns inside the classic editor.

It is available in make.powerapps.com: [image]

Also you can use something like https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MsCrmTools.MetadataDocumentGenerator/ to generate excel sheet with all the data about tables and columns in a solution.